# Unable to enter text to mail body in Hotmail, Selenium WebDriver, using Python bindings

Tags: python, webdriver, hotmail

I had a test script that was working, and it stopped working 2 weeks ago. The test is to login to Hotmail, click on new mail, fill in email address, subject, and text in the body, and send the email. Currently I can't enter text into the body of the mail. I tried with ID, CSS, and Xpath. I also tried using the select frame but to no avail. I have attached the Python code and would appreciate help...

The aim of the script is to capture the traffic via Wireshark specifically for Hotmail send mail, with the current Hotmail protocol.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class HotmailloginpythonWebdriver(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://login.live.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_hotmailloginpython_webdriver(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1321965448&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx&lc=1033&id=64855&mkt=en-us&cbcxt=mai&snsc=1")
        driver.find_element_by_id("i0116").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("i0116").send_keys("address@hotmail.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("i0118").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("i0118").send_keys("password")
        driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("h_inboxCount").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("NewMessage").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("AutoCompleteTo$InputBox").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("AutoCompleteTo$InputBox").send_keys("address@hotmail.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("fSubject").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("fSubject").send_keys("testsubject")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body..RichText").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body..RichText").send_keys("gggggggggggg")
        driver.find_element_by_id("SendMessage").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("c_signout").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible that Microsoft is blocking the automated service(like Selenium) which tries to access the Hotmail or live.com page. According to the Terms of Service( TOS) at Microsoft you can use automates service to login etc. Here is what TOS (Point Number#2) says:

*You must not use the service to harm others or the service. For example, you must not use the service to harm, threaten, or harass another person, organization, or Microsoft. You must not: damage, disable, overburden, or impair the service (or any network connected to the service); resell or redistribute the service or any part of it; use any unauthorized means to modify, reroute, or gain access to the service or attempt to carry out these activities; or **use any automated process or service (such as a bot, a spider, periodic caching of information stored by Microsoft, or metasearching) to access or use the service.***

Full text is available here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/microsoft-service-agreement.

I had similar experience myself once testing something with Twitter UI. Maybe you can look for a third party service that can help you login via SMTP or POP3 etc. to measure network traffic instead of using frontend UI.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with cookies. Maybe you removed the cookies from your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the script until the password typing or until

```
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
```

to see if it works fine. Perhaps MS changed their UI so it would be nice to debug your app from that point to see if you have to modify your script to update object id's.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Xpath not id. In xpath you can use following-sibling.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "F:\\batch230\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //open hotmail site
    driver.get("http://www.hotmail.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //do login
    driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("mail id");
    driver.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //compose mail
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title,'new message')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@role='textbox'])[1]"))
    .sendKeys("er.anil900@gmail.com",Keys.TAB,"selenium"
            ,Keys.TAB,"Hi",Keys.ENTER,"How are you");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //send mail
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@title='Send'])[1]")).click();        
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //do logout
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@role='menuitem'])[11]"));
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.click(e).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign out']"));
    a.click(e1).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.close();
```